# Variable in javascript file not accessible in object property

Tags: javascript, scope, extjs3

I have the following problem. I have a JS-file which has a handful of variables. Those I initialize in a function:

```
var currentYear;
var previousYear;
var urlQuarterDates;
var urlHalfYear;
var urlYear;
var urlMonth;
var urlProposalsSentAndReceived; //= '/Marketing/ListProposalsSentAndReceived';
var urlProposalsResponsibleMonth;

function initTabReportProposalsMonth(_currentYear, _previousYear, _urlViewProposal,
_urlQuarterDates, _urlHalfYear, _urlYear, _urlMonth, _urlProposalsSentAndReceived, 
_urlProposalsResponsibleMonth) {
    currentYear = _currentYear;
    previousYear = _previousYear;
    urlQuarterDates = _urlQuarterDates;
    urlHalfYear = _urlHalfYear;
    urlYear = _urlYear;
    urlMonth = _urlMonth;
    urlProposalsSentAndReceived = _urlProposalsSentAndReceived;
    urlProposalsResponsibleMonth = _urlProposalsResponsibleMonth;
}
```

I have defined an event handler in the same JS-file:

```
function onPeriodSelect(combo, rec, i) {
    var conn = new Ext.data.Connection();
    var params = { }; 
    switch(rec.get('myId'))
    {
        case _currentQuarter1:
            conn.url = urlQuarterDates;
            params.y = currentYear;
            params.index = 1;
            break;
    }
    reload(); //
}
```

The variables urlQuarterDates and currentYear are readily accessible. So far, so good...

I also have an ExtJs Grid with a data store which is declared inline:

```
var gridSentAndReceived = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    title: 'Totaal',
    autoHeight: true,
    autoWidth: true,
    store: new Ext.data.Store({
        id: 'idStoreSentAndReceived',
        proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({ url: urlProposalsSentAndReceived, 
            timeout: 1800000 }),
        reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader(
            {
                root: 'rows'
            },
            [
                { name: 'Status' },
                { name: 'nrOfProposals' },
                { name: 'TotalRevenueHardware' },
                { name: 'TotalRevenueYearly' },
                { name: 'TotalRevenueHours' }
            ]),
        remoteSort: false
    }),
    frame: true,
    iconCls: 'icon-grid',
        columns: [
        ...   
    ],
    viewConfig: {
        forceFit: true
    }
});
```

The reload() function calls the load of the store of gridSentAndReceived. This generates an exception: the url is not defined at all. If I initialize the url right at its declaration (which is currently commented out' it works fine. When I browse using the debugger it shows that urlProposalsSentAndReceived *is* initialized. Still, it claims there is no URL.

This seems to be a scope problem, since variables are accessible from the event handler but obviously not elsewhere. Anybody knows how to fix it? The URLs are created using server tags and those cannot be put in JS files. I wouldn't enjoy putting them directly in the JS file as a text string. Is there a possible solution?

**Update**

I have tried a few more things but nothing works.

I have tried:

```
'beforeload': function (store, options) {
    store.proxy.setUrl('/Marketing/ListProposalsSentAndReceived');
}
```

but even that didn't work. Still got the same exception. I really have no clue why that failed though, I took the code from the [ExtJs Documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.data.HttpProxy) under 'api'.

Now I have no choice but hardcoding the urls in my js-file though I'd very much prefer to use servertags and add them dynamically. Hopefully, one day, I'll find a solution rather than getting runtime errors when I change the location of a controller action.

Comment: _When I browse using the debugger it shows that urlProposalsSentAndReceived is initialized_ what do you mean by initialized? In debug mode, if you place a breakpoint where the `gridSentAndReceived` object is instanciated, what is the value of `urlProposalsSentAndReceived` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a scope issue. At the time you run your code `urlProposalsSentAndReceived` is not defined. If you set that variable via an event handler, the value is always set after `gridSentAndReceived` is initialized.

Comment: So I need to initialize the variables in an event handler of some sort? That would do the trick? Like the onBeforeLoad event of the datastore? That way I ensure it's set when I load...

Comment: I do not know, what `load()` does, but unless `initTabReportProposalsMonth()` is not called, `urlProposalsSentAndReceived` stays undefined.

Comment: initTabReportProposalsMonth() is called from outside the JS-file. It shows that in an event handler I can access the initialized variables, but from a function I can't. That means I can use onBeforeLoad(store) { store.url = urlProposalsSentAndReceived } or load({url = urlProposalsSentAndReceived}) from an event handler. I am going to try this out Friday and I'll post the results here afterwards. Thanks for your help!